# Filter based on first and last occurrences of different events

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, filter, window-functions

I have a dataframe with id, timestamp and an activity-code. I want to remove the rows in the data frame for each id between the first occurrence of one activity-code and the last occurrence of another activity-code.

[image]

Let's say I have a dataframe as shown above and I need to filter all activities between the first occurrence of activity-function c and the last occurrence of activity-function f. I need this to happen for all the trnum.

Here's what I tried doing:

```py
w = Window.partitionBy('trnum').orderBy('activitylogdate').rowsBetween(Window.unboundPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df_updated = df.withColumn("ignore_col",
    sum(when(
        (col("activitylogdate") >= list(df.filter((col("activityfunccode") == "c")).select(first('activitylogdate')).collect()[0])[0]) &
        (col("activitylogdate") <= list(df.filter((col("activityfunccode") == "f")).select(last('activitylogdate')).collect()[0])[0])
        , 1)
        .otherwise(0)
    ).over(w)
).orderBy("activitylogdate")
```

The idea here is to create a new column and remove all the rows later with value non zero after the above operation

This doesn't work. It only works for the first window and the end condition doesn't work at all. Can someone please help me?

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create several windows for this. The following code assumes that you have both, c and f, in every partition.

Setup:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1234, "a", 1),
     (1234, "b", 2),
     (1234, "j", 3),
     (1234, "c", 4),
     (1234, "d", 5),
     (1234, "f", 6),
     (1234, "e", 7),
     (1234, "f", 8),
     (1234, "t", 9),
     (1235, "a", 1),
     (1235, "c", 2),
     (1235, "x", 3),
     (1235, "f", 4),
     (1235, "t", 5)],
    ["trnum", "activityfunccode", "activitylogdate"])
```

Script:

```py
w1 = W.partitionBy("trnum", "activityfunccode").orderBy(F.desc("activitylogdate"))
w2 = W.partitionBy("trnum", "activityfunccode").orderBy("activitylogdate")
w3 = W.partitionBy("trnum").orderBy("activitylogdate")

df = df.withColumn("f_last", F.when((F.row_number().over(w1) == 1) & (F.col("activityfunccode") == "f"), 1))
df = df.withColumn("c_first", F.when((F.row_number().over(w2) == 1) & (F.col("activityfunccode") == "c"), 1))
df = df.withColumn("group", F.sum(F.coalesce("c_first", "f_last")).over(w3))
df = df.filter(((F.col("group") != 1) | F.isnull("group")) & F.isnull("f_last"))
df = df.drop("c_first", "f_last", "group")

df.show()
# +-----+----------------+---------------+
# |trnum|activityfunccode|activitylogdate|
# +-----+----------------+---------------+
# | 1234|               a|              1|
# | 1234|               b|              2|
# | 1234|               j|              3|
# | 1234|               t|              9|
# | 1235|               a|              1|
# | 1235|               t|              5|
# +-----+----------------+---------------+
```